# Is it possible to override the function called by add button in Share Menu of AddThis API for ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, addthis

I have implemented [AddThis](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381273-addthis-for-ios-documentation#.T6DXIO3aaeU) API for ios and I want to override the method that is called by addbutton on Right  side of top bar as displayed in image below:

[image]

The main Problem is that I can't see the implementation file of AddThis API.And I want to add LinkedIn option here By default.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to override the add button but want to modify the list of default sharing options, right?

Comment: Yes I want to modify default sharing option.But do not want to override button I want to override the method that is called by the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to add default options that is:

```
[AddThisSDK setFavoriteMenuServices:@"facebook",@"twitter",@"linkedin",@"delicious",@"tumblr",nil];
```